# Check if FileReader is the same file

Tags: groovy

Sample code:

```
def fn = 'abc.log'
def r1 = new FileReader(fn)
Thread.sleep(60 * 1000)
def r2 = new FileReader(fn)
```

Let's say the log file rolls often, but based on size it's not predictable when, depending on the "traffic". Is there a way to confirm that the readers `r1` and `r2` point to the same file (i.e. whether the fill rolled or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you aren't restricted to only using the `FileReader` class. This solution uses other classes with the string of the filename.

For my first attempt, I found [Files.isSamePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)). This seemed like a decent candidate based on the name... After creating the first path, I moved `file.txt` to `file.txt.1` and touched a new `file.txt`.

```
groovy:000> path1 = FileSystems.default.getPath("tmp", "file.txt")
===> tmp/file.txt
groovy:000> path2 = FileSystems.default.getPath("tmp", "file.txt")
===> tmp/file.txt
groovy:000> Files.isSameFile(path1, path2)
===> true
```

No luck here.

Next I found [Files.getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)). It looks like this might work if there's a created date attribute. Bingo! [BasicFileAttributes.creationTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#creationTime()).

```
groovy:000> fileTime = Files.getAttribute(path1, "creationTime")
===> 2014-10-21T17:30:31Z
groovy:000> assert fileTime != Files.getAttribute(path1, "creationTime")
===> null
```

In the above example, I moved `file.txt` to `file.txt.2` and touched a new `file.txt`. Note that I didn't change `path1`. This reads the current value of the attribute, so you'll need to store the initial value in a variable to compare with the later attribute value.

Comment: Thanks @doelleri - I actually think I am restricted to readers. The reason - I want to open all files, confirm they are the ones I want to open and then process them after that. Might work in the log rolling example, as I can check the `.log` file only per what you said and repeat opening of the readers. Would still like to see if there's a general solution (i.e. I open N files twice and if the readers match, I'm fine to process them).

Comment: You'll have to actually read the files to see if they're the same then. The reader objects will never be the same.

Comment: Also note, while it shouldn't matter in this case, per http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime it's not possible in Linux to get file creation time. `creationTime` attribute looks to be giving the same value as `lastModificationTime`.